# Confusion over a change of bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, bilinear-form

Suppose I am given that a bilinear form $\phi(u,v)$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is represented by a diagonalisable matrix $M$ with respect to the pair of bases $\{u_i\}$ and $\{v_i\}$. If I wanted to find a pair of bases $\{\tilde{u_i}\}$ and $\{\tilde{v_i}\}$ with respect to which $\phi$ is represented by a diagonal matrix, would I simply need to diagonalise $M$ i.e. find $P$ such that:

$$\Delta =PMP^{-1}$$

and then see where $P$ sends $\{u_i\}$ and $\{v_i\}?$ This feels wrong but I am not sure how else to answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets consider bases $\mathcal{B}_{1} = \{u_{i}\}$, $\mathcal{B}_{2} = \{v_{i}\}$, $\mathcal{B}_{1}^{\prime} = \{ u_{i}^{\prime}\}$, $\mathcal{B}_{2}^{\prime} = \{ v_{i}^{\prime}\}$.  You have that
$$\phi(w_{1},w_{2}) = [w_{1}]_{\mathcal{B}_{1}}^{T} M [w_{2}]_{\mathcal{B}_{2}}$$
and also that
$$\phi(w_{1},w_{2}) = [w_{1}]_{\mathcal{B}_{1}^{\prime}}^{T} \Delta [w_{2}]_{\mathcal{B}_{2}^{\prime}}$$
for some diagonal matrix $\Delta$.  You should use the change of bases matrices to get the correct formula from here.

If you can find $PMP^{-1} = \Delta$, then you can take $P = A_{1}^{T}$ and $P^{-1} = A_{2}$ and use that info to recover your bases (by interpreting them as the correct change-of-basis matrices, see the comment below).

Comment: Thanks, yes I am sure this is what is being asked. So how would I use change of bases matrices without knowing the second pair of bases in the first place?

Comment: In principal, let $A_{i}$ be the change of basis matrix from $\mathcal{B}_{i}^{\prime}$ to $\mathcal{B}_{i}$.  Then $$[w_{1}]_{\mathcal{B}_{1}^{\prime}}^{T} \Delta [w_{2}]_{\mathcal{B}_{2}^{\prime}} = (A_{1}[w_{1}]_{\mathcal{B}_{1}^{\prime}})^{T} M (A_{2}[w_{2}]_{\mathcal{B}_{2}^{\prime}}) = [w_{1}]_{\mathcal{B}_{1}^{\prime}}^{T}A_{1}^{T} M A_{2}[w_{2}]_{\mathcal{B}_{2}^{\prime}}$$ so you want $A_{1}^{T} M A_{2} = \Delta$.  In practice, the second method I mentioned is easier.

Comment: Thank you this is great. One last thing: for given $\Delta$ are $A_1,A_2$ unique? It feels like they wouldn't be but then I could get several possible bases under which $\phi$ has the form $\Delta\dots$

Comment: They are probably not unique.  In general, if $M$ is diagonalizable, you have some choices to make in choosing a basis of eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

You don't typically coordinatize bilinear forms by pairs of bases, but rather only by one base, i.e. the matrix $M$ of $\phi$ with respect to the base $U$ is given by $M_{i,j} = \phi(u_i, u_j)$. Switching to a different base is realized by a *congruence transformation*, that is, a transformation of the form $M \mapsto P^T M P$ with $P$ a regular matrix.

Algorithmically, you would try to transform $M$ to diagonal form by performing congruence operations. This means that after performing an operation on the columns of $M$, you immediately perform the corresponding operations on the rows.

Example: Say you swap columns 1 and 4. Then immediately afterwards, you have to swap rows 1 and 4. This algorithm can also give you the transformation matrix $P$ if you start with an identity matrix and perform the column operations on it in parallel to $M$.